# Migrate managed metadata with SPMT

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, migration, managed-metadata, term-store

[This document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/spmt-settings) says it is possible to migrate metadata terms using some settings, but I cannot understand where to find this settings in the tool.

I have also searched quite a lot and could not find any information about this.

My requirements are to migrate terms store first than we will have a custom migration tool for migrating publishing pages to modern pages which which have a metadata column. This is from onprem to SPO.

Answer (score 0):

Spmt support I think I will check, but most powerful for resolve this scenario it's use powershell and import and export store, sets and terms.